# Internationalization of floats to display a , instead of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Rails display floating numbers with a . : `5.86` using the american way of displaying numbers. How can i make it display them the european way : `5,86` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `number_with_precision` helper method from the `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` module:

`number_with_precision(5.86, precision: 2, separator: ',') # => 5,86`